# Image mask over Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, css, slider, image-rotation, nivo-slider

I'm using [Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com), but want to place a PNG image over the slider so it only shows through the parts that are transparent. What would be the best way to do this using JavaScript or CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the demo using the code below to see how this can be done.  There are a lot of ways to do this so you should figure out what works best for your situation.  The code below wraps the slider and another relatively placed image inside of the same div.  A bit of CSS is used to position the the image and you can see the effect in action.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">

            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
                <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
            <div id="slider-mask"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer-wrapper {
    width:618px;
    height:246px;
    margin-left:190px;
}

#slider-mask {
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/mask.png) no-repeat;
    width:618px;
    height:246px;
    top:-246px;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**Image Used**
[image]

**Screenshot of the effect**
[image]

Comment: @GavinR: Glad it is working for you. Since you have accepted the answer, are you waiting for other answers before awarding the bounty?

Comment: Unfortunately, this method causes the navigation buttons that are overlaid, as well as any hyperlinks within the caption, to be completely unclickable.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen: Obviously but that's what the OP has asked for.  I agree that it's not something you generally want to be doing but it's not deserving of a downvote.  If you're trying to protect future generations of Nivo Slider users from harming themselves then a downvote of the question itself would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

look [this slider](http://dev.sirkruk.com/2011/04/02/galeria-zdjec-rvngallery-1-1/#english) ([example](http://dev.sirkruk.com/2011/04/02/galeria-zdjec-rvngallery-1-1/#example-en)).

Answer (score 1):

Just set the PNG to be absolute positioned and move it over top of the nivo slider. Make sure that the z-index is set to be above the slider.

Comment: I've tried absolutely positioning, but that positions the img absolutely on the page - not what i want.

Comment: You can make the absolute positioning relative to something else. Take a look at this and see if it helps: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: More specifically, create a parent div for both the image and the slider, and set it to position:relative. Then when you're absolute positioning the png, it will be positioned absolutely in the div.

Answer (score 1):

absolute positioned divs when placed with in relative positioned div than they give your required result.

position your nivo slider container as relative positioned and put the mask div within the nivo slider container and position that absolute.

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task from my designer, meaning to place some mask over the animations.

This was the easy part !!!
The complicated part was to:

- make links work again
- to have back animation pause on mouse over them;
- to place the controlNav buttons over the image and also make them work...

So, I had to develop and use this (done by me, and explained in detail over there):

- http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/1371-moving-controlnav-outside-slider-on-a-separate-container-wrapper
- http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/1375-trick-adding-custom-layer-for-anchors-on-images-completely-outside-the-slider

Maybe this will help others in the future ;)

Razvan

Comment: As Stackoverflow shall not depend on external links which might break in some time, it is advisable to include at least the important extracts of external sites into your answers.

Comment: @Nippey - you're right, haven't though that they will delete old discussions post, and I don't know if I have somewhere else that code so good explained and documented :(

The only place I still have it it's under the project I've needed it, so if there's someone interested I can try to grab the code and republish it here.